# How to poll for current time in a Service?

Tags: android, service, time

I did a search before asking so please don't tell me to do that.
I'm relatively new to Android so I get confused easily.

I'm making a simple app that changes the ringer volume according to time. For this purpose, I know I need a service that keeps running in the bg and monitor time. However, I really don't know how to approach this. I have the Professional Android Application Development book but haven't found anything that helps in there.

My question:

- How to constantly check time without destroying the battery

If my code is needed (as proof of me actually working on this), I'll post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a service. Use the AlarmManager class. Its like an alarm clock and it exactly what you need for this type of app.

Comment: What, so you think the app will be run constantly? :s
I don't want the app to run constantly. The user creates a profile specifying a time and ringer level (saved in shared preferences) and the service can then do its thing.

Comment: You set the alarm manager to wake your task periodically. Your task only runs when the alarm 'pops'. Set the interval to wake your task once a minute or so. Your task only takes a few milliseconds and will not be looping. Don't forget logic to turn off the alarm when you are done. Also, check out logic that resets the alarm after a power off or restart.

Comment: The task does not need to wake every minute. It already knows what time it needs to perform its duties so it only needs to wake at that time.

Answer (score 1):

> need a service that keeps running in the bg and monitor time

No. Actually that's not how to do it. Services on android are different than your normal windows service/unix daemon. They should do their job and then stop themself until they get started again - to save battery.

You should start your service at a certain point in time by using the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), it sends the launch intent to run the service. When the service is finished doing what it's supposed to do *(change the rintone volume here)*, use `Service.stopSelf()` to kill it.